# HTTP not being converted to HTTPS with HSTS

Tags: tls, http, firefox, hsts

I am looking up the behavior of HSTS on both HTTP and HTTPS websites, and their HTTP and HTTPS embedded resources. My understanding is that if an HSTS response header has been passed on by the server in an HTTPS response, or if the site's name is present on the HSTS preload list, then all the resources of that request would be sent on HTTPS.

However, while inspecting some sites via the Firefox Web Inspector, I am noticing some discrepancies. For example, here on `cnn.com` (an HTTP website), some of the requests of `doubleclick.net`'s subdomains are going over HTTP, even though it is present in the HSTS preload list over [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/refs/heads/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json) (with include_subdomains:true).

[image]

Just to test whether the root domain was sending the HSTS header, I navigated to the `ad.doubleclick.net` link in the location address bar which directed me to Double Click's main site `https://www.doubleclickbygoogle.com` Over here the HSTS header is being sent:

[image]

Yet, there is no effect on `doubleclick`'s requests on `cnn.com` when I reload:

[image]

Another interesting thing is that when I try to locate the source tag of request on the DOM by going to the Inspector tab, there is no such tag with `http://ad.doubleclick.net` (strung with some querystrings). The "Cause" and "Type" heading in the inspector seem to indicate its some tracker sort of a pixel.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on over here?

Comment: Check how the HSTS header was set.  Was it set at `secureupload.g.double.click.net` or `doubleclick.net` (I strongly suspect the former).

Comment: By where do you mean the host domain which sends the HSTS header response? That would be `https://doubleclickbygoogle.com` wouldn't it?

Comment: HSTS has a `includeSubDomains` directive.  If the main domain gives you HSTS with IncludeSubDomains that would be the case.  But it does not need to be.  A subdomain can set HSTS for itself, and other domains at the same level will not get it.  (I'm 80-90% sure of that, need to do more RFC reading)

Comment: Yep. From the RFC: `When establishing an HTTP connection to a given host, however instigated, the UA examines its cache of Known HSTS Hosts to see if there are any with domain names that are superdomains of the given host's domain name.  If any are found, and of those if any have the includeSubDomains directive asserted, then HSTS Policy applies to the given host.  Otherwise, HSTS Policy applies to the given host only if the given host is itself known to the UA as an HSTS Host`

Comment: So, the HSTS was set at the root/superdomain: `https://doubleclickbygoogle` which is the domain that `doubleclick.net` link is directed towards.

Comment: +1 for diligent `code` formatting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To cite from the source code you mention:

```
354  // Other Google-related domains that must use an acceptable certificate
355  // iff using SSL.
     ...
361  { "name": "doubleclick.net", "include_subdomains": true, "pins": "google" },
```

This means that the certificate is pinned **iff** the site is served over https. It does not mean that the site needs to be served over https. This is different for other domains where the `force-https` attribute is set:

```
264  { "name": "accounts.google.com", "include_subdomains": true, "mode": "force-https", "pins": "google" },
```

---

EDIT: based on the source code of Chromium  (function `TransportSecurityState::GetStaticDomainState` in `net/http/transport_security_state.cc`) I'll try to explain the information which can be seen in `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and how it relates to the static information from `net/http/transport_security_state_static.json` using the example `doubleclick.net`:

```
static_sts_domain: doubleclick.net
static_upgrade_mode: OPPORTUNISTIC
```

OPPORTUNISTIC is the default mode (`STSState::MODE_DEFAULT`). This means that it does not force HTTPS. The default mode is used since no explicit `force-https` setting was given in the configuration.

```
static_sts_include_subdomains: true
```

Since it does not enforce https this setting does not matter. But the value might be caused by the configuration of `include_subdomains` shown above even if this configuration line does not include `force-https`.

```
static_sts_observed: 1476162000
```

This is the build time of the static HSTS/HPKP list, i.e. 2016/09/04 in this case.

```
static_pkp_domain: doubleclick.net
static_pkp_include_subdomains: true
static_pkp_observed: 1476162000
static_spki_hashes: sha256/IPMbDAjLVSGntGO3WP53X/zilCVndez5YJ2+vJvhJsA=,sha256/7HIpactkIAq2Y49orFOOQKurWxmmSFZhBCoQYcRhJ3Y=,sha256/h6801m+z8v3zbgkRHpq6L29Esgfzhj89C1SyUCOQmqU=
```

These are the information about pinning. These have a direct relation to the settings shown above (i.e. `include_subdomains` and which pins should be used).

Comment: But isn't pinning different from `HSTS`, in the sense that the pins attribute is relevant only in the case when `HPKP` header has been sent. What I mean to say is that `HSTS` in itself is used as a solution for the situation when you have `http` links, and should be turned on when the root domain of that` HTTP` link has set the `include_subdomains` attribute. So, what then is the reason for `force-https`? And how does it connect with `pins' (which is used to decide the certificate we trust)

Comment: @QPTR: 'pin' is HPKP, 'force-https' is HSTS. You can have 'pin' without 'force-https' like in case of doubleclick. In this case 'pin' is only relevant if the site is accessed with https and ignored otherwise, i.e. the site is not forced to https. Forcing to https (HSTS) is only done if 'force-https' is set, no matter if combined with 'pin' or without.

Comment: So, basically `HSTS` applies if force-https is set in that list, and `HPKP` applies if pins has been set? Got it! So, basically since `doubleclick.net` has only `HPKP` policy specified, it means its not there in the `HSTS` list.

Comment: Just one more thing. Here on chrome when I look up in chrome://net-internals/#hsts, I get this policy: `static_sts_domain: doubleclick.net static_upgrade_mode: OPPORTUNISTIC
static_sts_include_subdomains: true
static_sts_observed: 1474693200
static_pkp_domain: doubleclick.net
static_pkp_include_subdomains: true`
Over here, what is the point of including static_sts_include_subdomains and static_pkp_include_subdomains separately? Shouldn't that mean that HSTS is actually specified for subdomains for HSTS as well, in addition to HPKP.

Comment: What I mean by that is, that given that they have their attributes separately listed, shouldn't that mean that HSTS for doubleclick has indeed been turned on inside Chrome (and chrome dev tools show the request in http as well). Or is it that include_subdomains inside the Chromium list (the one you quote) is just singly listed for both HSTS and HPKP. What happens if on a website, subdomains are included for HSTS but not for HPKP and similarly for max-age? Thanks for the answers, btw, I am just trying to clarify whether force-https is indeed the last word on HSTS.

Comment: @QPTR: I think the source code of the page is quite clear in this regard. Line 33,34: *mode: (optional string) "force-https" iff covered names should require HTTPS.*. And it also describes the meaning of `include_subdomains` to apply the given settings for pin and force-https to the subdomains.

Comment: @QPTR: see edit for more information based on analysis of source code.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed/awesome answer. I would just like to add (maybe you would like to comment on it), that I just found out that Firefox doesn't use Google's `HSTS` list as it is. It gets only those which have `force-https` enabled, sends them a request, and if an `HSTS` header is returned successfully and has max-age beyond a certain value, then only the website is preloaded. References: [https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2012/11/01/preloading-hsts/](1) [https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26703656/](2) So, I guess doubleclick gets filtered there on that first check of `force-https`

Answer (score 3):

HSTS only apply for the domain it's been set.

What you are looking for is upgrade-insecure-requests CSP directive.

> Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests

**In the HSTS preload list, doubleclick.net is NOT listed for HSTS for for key pinning.**

More details on https://scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/

Comment: CSP can only be set by the website though? What happens when do not have it set, yet still I want to ensure that embedded third-party requests go via HTTPS if their own root domains have set the HSTS header ?

Comment: As a user ? Using the extension httpseverywhere is the easiest way. If you prefer doing it manually, just visits manually an https webpage of a webpage of the website that set hsts, it will ensure you that all future requests use https...

Comment: True, but when I visited the home domain of doubleclick, that is https://doubleclickbygoogle, and then later reloaded the page, it was still continuing onwards as http. No effect. It could be that as Steffen says, the policy for doubleclick.net only applies for HSTS and not for HPKP. But I'll try this for some other requests.